# Full status of Mercurial local repository

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

It occurs quite often that I want to know the full status of my local copy of a project, compared to the remote repository. By full status, I mean the following:

- Are there some uncommitted changes locally?
- Are there some unpushed commits locally?
- Are there some unpulled commits remotely?
- Am I on head of default branch?

I know that I can use some graphical tool such as HgView or TortoiseHg, or even my IDE to deal with Mercurial repositories, but I find it more convenient to use CLI when working with several projects/repos at the same time.

The way I am doing currently is by using an alias

```
alias hg_full='hg incoming; hg outgoing; hg status'
```

If everything is fine (i.e. local synchronized with remote), I then ensure being on head of default by

```
hg update default
```

This approach is perfectly working, but when I work with a slow remote repository, it is quite annoying to wait for both the incoming and outgoing command to return before performing the update.

Is there some way (by the mean of an extension or a more advanced command) to get a full status summary of the local copy compare to remote repository without performing `hg in` and `hg out` sequentially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `hg summary --remote` might be exactly what you're looking for:

```
$ hg summary --remote
parent: 1:c15d3f90697a tip
 commit message here
branch: default
commit: 1 modified
update: (current)
remote: 1 or more incoming, 1 outgoing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself some network traffic by doing `hg incoming --bundle <filename>`, which fetches the incoming changesets and stores them in a bundle file. You can then run `hg outgoing` (or `hg pull`) against the bundle file, which doesn't use the network at all.

```
hg incoming --bundle incoming.bundle   # Creates the bundle
hg outgoing incoming.bundle

hg pull incoming.bundle
hg update default
```